# Which of these pages are correct- "Trust Jake with" Or "Trust with Jake"

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

Do these sentences have the same meaning?

> 1. These are the people I trust Jake with.
> 2. These are the people I trust with Jake.

Which one means:
*"I can trust that Jake is safe if he was with these people."*

Comment: 'People I _trust Jake_ with' could imply that you trust Jake not to harm these people, so (2) is better - or you could say 'I can entrust Jake to these people'.

Comment: It might help to "extend" them as 1: *These are the people I trust Jake **to be** with* and 2: *Those are the people I trust **to be** with Jake* (the two classes of people *might* be the same, but not necessarily).)

Comment: Thank you very much, Kate and Monica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.1 means Jake is the one who needs to be trusted.

No.2 means the people are the ones to be trusted.

Trusted to do what, or in what way, we do not know.

No.2 has the meaning you ask about.

Comment: Thank you so much @Tim